# how to convert a concatenate string of characters to decimal numbers

Tags: c

Basically the code below result in in a concatenate string of characters that is placed in "dec". The memory reading from the function which goes through the line of code below is 101E34 which is "dec" should be converted to 163052. How do I convert that string?

```
   for (int j = 0; j <2; j++)
       {
           char temp[100]= "";
           sprintf(temp, "%x", readArray[j]);
           if (strlen(temp) < 4)
              {
                  char dec[100] = "";
                  for (int r = 0; r < 4 - strlen(temp); r++)
                      {
                          strcat(dec,"0");
                      }
                          strcat(dec, temp);
               }
         }
```

Comment: why would it be converted to `163052`?!

Comment: Looking at the AScii table, 10 is 16,1E is 30, 34 is 52

Comment: from hex to decimal

Comment: To note its just a string of characters I have

Comment: Use bit/byte wise operation and combine with hex to decimal conversion.

Comment: @SoumyaKanti how do I do that?Can you show an example

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  char input[] = "101E34";
  char output[100];
  int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
  for(i = 0; i < 6;) {
    if(input[i] >= '0' && input[i] <= '9')
      j = (input[i] - '0')<< 4;
    else if(input[i] >= 'A' && input[i] <= 'Z')
      j = (input[i] - 'A' + 10)<< 4;
    else if(input[i] >= 'a' && input[i] <= 'z')
      j = (input[i] - 'a' + 10)<< 4;


    if(input[i + 1] >= '0' && input[i + 1] <= '9')
      j = j + (input[i + 1] - '0');
    else if(input[i + 1] >= 'A' && input[i + 1] <= 'Z')
      j = j + (input[i + 1] - 'A' + 10);
    else if(input[i + 1] >= 'a' && input[i + 1] <= 'z')
      j = j + (input[i + 1] - 'a' + 10);

    k += snprintf((output + k), (100 - k), "%d", j);
    i = i + 2;
  }
  puts(output);
  return 0;
}
```

The only restriction is on the size of `output`. You may need to dynamically allocate it if the `input` is big or changes in every run.

Comment: And, BTW, `main()` should return `int` not `void`.

Comment: Why not? It is a free-standing `C` code, not a library, and the code is meant to give an example. And this program is not meant to run as a service where you need to look into the exit value. I am well aware of `int main(...)` vs `void main()` debate. Unless the `gcc` compiler going to give me error while compiling `void main()`, I will continue to use it.

Comment: It's is the implementation/environment that is "*free-standing*" or "*hosted*", not the code. And BTW, I did not down-vote.